# Javascript Prompt Window not opening with if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple Javascript app that takes an input from the user through a prompt window. When I only have the single "if" statement, then the prompt window opens up fine. However, when I have the "else-if" statement after, the window no longer pops up. Is there something I am missing here? Here is the piece of code:

```
    var gender = prompt("Is the person male or female? (enter M or F)");
    var male = "M";
    var female = "F";
    var a, b, c, d, e, f;

    if(gender.localeCompare(male) == 0)
    {
         a = -216.0475144;
         b = 16.2606339;
         c = -0.002388645;
         d = -0.00113732;
         e = 7.01863 * (Math.pow(10,-6));
         f = -1.291 * (Math.pow(10,-8));
    }
    else if (gender.localeCompare(female) == 0) //If this portion is commented out, then it works fine
    {
         a = 594.31747775582;
         b = -27.23842536447;
         c = 0.82112226871;
         d = -0.00930733913;
         e = 0.00004731582;
         f = =0.00000009054;
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("Please try again!");
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it was caused by a typographical error. Look into using a JavaScript debugger next time to catch these yourself! Good luck!

Comment: @user2962702 - please delete your question because a simple typographical error is of no ongoing use to the stackoverflow community.

Comment: I voted to close also.  No reason to keep a simple typographical error around in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f = =0.00000009054;` syntax error is the easiest to find error. next time pls find it by yourself. use the console of your browser! In the statement is one =-character too much.

Comment: I appreciate the fast response! I was not aware of the browser console until now. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. pls select a response as the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the final line of the second block

```
f = =0.00000009054;
```

change it to

```
f = 0.00000009054;
```

Comment: Thanks! Caught it a minute after